# Velocity of points in a rigid body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, vectors

I'm trying to derive the following statement:

> Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a rigid body. Then there is an unique vector $\vec{\omega}$ such that for every pair of points $P,Q\in \mathcal{B}$ the following equation holds:
> $$\vec{v}_P-\vec{v}_Q=\vec{\omega}\times (P-Q),$$
> where $\vec{v}_P,\vec{v}_Q$ are the velocities of $P$ and $Q$.

**My proof attempt**

Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a rigid body we have that for every pair of points $P,Q\in \mathcal{B}$:
$$\|P-Q\|^2=0$$
$$(P-Q)\cdot (P-Q)=0$$
Differentiating with respect to time:
$$(P-Q)\cdot (\vec{v}_P-\vec{v}_Q)=0$$
Since $(P-Q)$ is orthogonal to $(\vec{v}_P-\vec{v}_Q)$ there is a vector $\vec{\omega}_{PQ}$ (in general it could depend from $P$ and $Q$) such that:
$$\vec{v}_P-\vec{v}_Q=\vec{\omega}_{PQ}\times (P-Q),$$
Now, how do I prove that $\vec{\omega}_{PQ}=\vec{\omega}_{RS}$ for all points $P,Q,R,S \in \mathcal{B}$?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/680029/195949

Comment: The equation defining $\vec \omega_{PQ}$ does not define it uniquely. You cannot expect to prove that $\vec\omega_{PQ} = \vec \omega_{RS}$ with only this equation.

Comment: Thank you, and what should I do?